# How to recovery model from 'experiment.cbsnapshot' file in CatboostClassifier?

Tags: python, catboost, catboostregressor

I was training using by CatboostClassifier. Then training is killed, But I checked `save_snapshot=True`, because of the `experiment.cbsnapshot` file created. How to recovery model from `experiment.cbsnapshot`?

```py
model.fit(train_data, train_labels, use_best_model=True, save_snapshot=True, snapshot_file="catboost_info/experiment.cbsnapshot")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the same experiment one more time with the same parameters. It will see the snapshot and start training from the iteration, where it has stopped.